# Quad form program not solving correctly

Tags: python

```
import cmath
a = float(input("A: "))
b = float(input("B: "))
c = float(input("C: "))
negB = float(b*-1)
sqrtVAR = (b**2-4*a*c)
plus = (negB+cmath.sqrt(sqrtVAR)/2*a)
minus = (negB-cmath.sqrt(sqrtVAR)/2*a)
print(plus)
print(minus)
```

when i run it negB does not add with the rest of the equation and the answers come out wrong anyway

Comment: What are sample inputs? What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: You've forgotten parentheses around `2*a`.

Comment: You need to add parentheses to expressions to override the default order the mathematical operators in it are executed — which is, with a couple of exceptions, generally left-to-right. See [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) section of the language documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As pacholik mentions, you've forgotten some parentheses, so your calculation is incorrect.

Also, you are unnecessarily calculating the same square root twice.

The code below adds a function, `quad`, to test that the found roots are actually zeroes of the equation.

```
import cmath

a = float(input("A: "))
b = float(input("B: "))
c = float(input("C: "))

def quad(x):
    return a*x*x + b*x +c

d = cmath.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)
x1 = (-b + d) / (2*a)
x2 = (-b - d) / (2*a)

print(x1, quad(x1))
print(x2, quad(x1))
```

**test**

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3
(-1+1.41421356237j) 0j
(-1-1.41421356237j) 0j
```